# Abaixo a tag [popunder]!

Tags: debate

Essa *tag* tem duas perguntas apenas. Uma apareceu hoje, a outra no começo do ano.

[popunder](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/popunder)

A *tag* incomoda por três motivos, em motivo crescente de importância:

- <rant> *popunder* é uma forma muito baixa e antiprofissional de publicidade. Não atende ao cliente da publicidade, que não tem seu produto exposto. E ainda incomoda o usuário. Além disso essa forma de praga anda junto com malwares da mesma forma que manteiga anda junto com pão. A minha consideração aqui é mais ética do que técnica.
- Os navegadores modernos, e em especial extensões bem populares têm lá suas formas de bloquear *popunder's*. Se alguém pergunta sobre como fazer *popunder*, uma resposta que funcione com certeza vai ser alguma forma de contornar as proteções do usuário. Por esse mesmo motivo, a resposta tende a ficar obsoleta rapidamente.
- A *tag* [javascript](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) atende perfeitamente os casos em que utilizaria [popunder](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/popunder).

Podemos mandar essa *tag* pra sete palmos abaixo da terra?

**Edição:** tomei a liberdade de substituir a *tag* [popunder](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/popunder) por [javascript](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) nas duas perguntas em que aparecia, pelo motivo que já citei acima. A tag está sem perguntas agora.

Comment: _Agreed_. Pode derrubá-la, ao meu ver.

Comment: Desculpem minha ignorância, mas o que é popunder?

Comment: @LeandroFelipeMoreira muitos sites são financiados por anúncios. Para aumentar a renda, alguns sites exageram na quantidade de anúncios. Isso torna o visual do site desagradável e afasta usuários. Para contornar isso, pessoas maldosas usam o *popunder*, que é uma propaganda que é carregada no seu navegador junto com o site, mas que fica em uma janela separada e que não recebe foco imediato.